# How shld I create a helper file in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, helper

I know there a lot of resources that answer the question - but I am confused after going through resources.

I have my layout file in

```
module/
    Application/
        view/
            layout/
                 layout.phtml
```

I need to create a helper file for layout.phtml.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is very Easy to create our own helper in Zend.

As i seen you are using Zend framework 2 then you can easily go to this step

Just understand [LINK](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/zend-framework-2-create-your-custom-view-helper/) and you can solve your problem

Comment: glad to help you. @Stacy J

Answer (score 0):

To create a new Zend View Helper file:

1. In the PHP Explorer, right-click the relevant helpers folder in your
   Zend Framework Project and select New | Zend Framework Item | Zend
   View Helper. The New Zend View Helper Wizard will be displayed.
2. Ensure the source folder is correct, or click Browse to change.
3. Enter the Helper's Prefix.
4. Enter the Helper's name. This will be the name of the Helper file. The Helper's class name will be automatically created in the
   format _.
5. Click Next. The Select PHP Template dialog is displayed.
6. Select the New Zend View Helper template, and click Finish.

**Zend View Helper phpDoc block comments must be in the format:**

```
/**
* <Helper's_Name> helper
*
* @uses viewHelper <Helper's_Prefix>
*/
```

http://files.zend.com/help/Mobile/Zend-Studio-10/Advanced/content/creating_a_zend_view_helper_file.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=Helper|helpers|helper|Helpers